# D3 - data format required for cal-heatmap calendar heatmap?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, calendar, heatmap

I'm trying to plot `calendar-heatmap` from this [**link**](http://kamisama.github.io/cal-heatmap/#home).

I searched all over the documenation but i couldn't find any sample file for the `data-format`.

Here's a [**link**](http://kamisama.github.io/cal-heatmap/#documentation) for documentation but there's no sample file for it.

In the documentation I find this data being imported `datas-years.json`. But I don't have any clue on how the format is. Someone please help me on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cal-Heatmap expects data in a JSON object in the following format:

```
{
    "timestamp1": value1,
    "timestamp2": value2,
    "timestamp3": value3,
    ...
}
```

Value can be any number (integer or float).

All timestamp are in seconds. Seconds are 'UTC seconds' (sometimes also called 'epoch seconds' or 'unix seconds') as the number of seconds since at 01-01-1970 00:00:00 for the GMT date/time provided. Here is [UTC second calculator](http://www.mbari.org/staff/rich/utccalc.htm).

Today we are around 1.388.000.000 UTC seconds. The sample on the site shows data from year 2000, that is why its UTC seconds are around 946.000.000 as you saw in the JSON file sample.

Good thing is that you can find easily on the internet how to obtain UTC seconds from other time formats, and than you will be able to create a data file that Cal-Heatmap expects. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a random test program to randomly generate the json file.

Scenario: Show submission 12 months hence including the current month. If you have defined start -> point it to the month 11 months before the current month and the json file should work perfectly.

```
var data = generateRandomData();

            function getRandomInt(min, max) {
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
            }


            function generateRandomData(){
                var date = new Date();

                var mind = date.valueOf();
                var maxd = date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 11);

                var mins = 0;
                var maxs = 40;

                var retobj = {};

                for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
                    retobj[getRandomInt(mind,maxd)/1000] = getRandomInt(mins,maxs);
                }

                return retobj;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Cal-heatmap expects data in JSON format

```
{
    "timestamp1": value1,
    "timestamp2": value2,
    "timestamp3": value3,
    ...
}
```

As already said, timestamps should always be in seconds, and not in milliseconds (javascript default).

You either put your data in a file, then pass that file in the `data` option, or directly pass a javascript variable:

```
var d = {946705035: 25};
var cal = new CalHeatMap();
cal.init({data: d}); // For variable
cal.init({data: "path/to/file.json"}) // For file, or URI
```

Cal-heatmap can also understand file in CSV and TSV.

In the case cal-heatmap don't/can't understand your data:

#### If the data is from a variable

Convert your data in javascript to a JSON object before passing it to Cal-heatmap

#### If the data is from a file/uri

Set the right `datatype`, then use the after [`afterLoadData()`](http://kamisama.github.io/cal-heatmap/#afterLoadData) callback to read the file and convert the text to a json object.

`datatype` specify the parser engine used to read the file. If your file is json, csv, or tsv formatted, set it to `json`, etc... else, set it to `txt` to read the file as plain text.

You can study the [Google Analytics](http://kamisama.github.io/cal-heatmap/#google-analytics-example) example, it illustrates the use of `data`, `datatype`, and `afterLoadData()` callback.

Answer (score -1):

You can retrieve the JSON file directly and inspect it at http://kamisama.github.io/cal-heatmap/datas-years.json.

Comment: That's a Unix timestamp, i.e. the seconds since January 1st 1970 midnight GMT. You can use any date format you like though, but will have to adjust the parsing code.

Comment: No, he has to use UTC time.

Comment: Why does it have to be UTC?